# Retry request without an increasing delay but a fix one (ex: every 30 sec)

Tags: python-requests, python-3.6, delay

Currently my code increases the delay between each retry : `0s`, `2s`, `4s`, `8s`, `16s`... but I would like to retry a failed request every 30 seconds (even after the first fail).

It seems simple, but I can't find a way to do this with  `requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry`

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
url = "http://192.168.1.10/last_data.json"
s = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=15,
                backoff_factor=1,
                status_forcelist=[ 500, 502, 503, 504 ])
s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
response = s.get(url)
```

I know I can use time.sleep(30), but this isn't [good practice](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-practice-with-retries-with-requests).

Comment: What if you just set `backoff_factor` to 0?

Comment: OK may how do I specify `30 seconds`